# DAX query to add a calculated column to power bi table which calculates sum of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

What will be the DAX query to add a calculated column to power bi table which calculates sum of a column including those rows only where a certain condition is met. For eg.

If the table is as follows:

```
id    city       count
1      x         2
2      y         3
3      z         1
1      u         6
2      v         3
```

I want to add a column total count to the table and not a measure.
The total count is calculated by adding counts based on same id.
The expected table should be as follows:

```
id    city       count    totalcount
1      x         2        8       
2      y         3        6
3      z         1        1
1      u         6        8
2      v         3        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMX` with a `FILTER`:

```
totalcount = SUMX(FILTER(MyTable, MyTable[id] = EARLIER(MyTable[id])),[count])
```